# Configuration Properties missing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Missing Configuration Properties in Visual Studio 2015

I wanted to change the configuration properties of my project such as target framework e.t.c but I can't seem to find the relevant properties.

I appreciate any assistance. Thanks!

Here is an image showing the missing properties:

[image]

Comment: What type of project is this? Does it *have* configuration properties? Is it something you created using the AWS SDK? Did you check the AWS docs and tutorials?

Comment: Did you create a *Node.js* AWS Lambda project perhaps?

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, this is a sample AWS Lambda project created using the AWS Toolkit

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your solution and click properties.

[image]

Comment: That's not what the question is about.

Comment: Given the way he has framed his questioned, I assumed that's what he is talking about. If it's not I am sorry.